# Please identify this weird 80's sci fi movie with house containing monster

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I came upon this movie years ago on late night TV. Here's what I remember: 
A house. An orange backdrop. A teenage boy with dark hair and a girl, trying to escape the house. There is a monster inside. The monster is your classic body-horror type - tentacles, malformed, green, mutated. As she tries to escape the house, the monster uses its tentacles to pin the girl down and rip off the top of her shirt. The boy rescues her and they run outside. What is this movie?

Comment: What else do you remember that happened in the movie?